# Having issues with SQLite query returning too many rows on join

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

First my SQL is extremely rusty and I believe I need to do a group by here, but every time I try I get an error

***The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator***

I have the following tables

```
Transactions
TransId | AccountId | PayeeId | TransAmount | CatId | SubCatId | TransDate
1       | 1         | 1       | 100.00      | 2     | 1        | 01/02/2018
2       | 1         | -1      | 50.00       | 3     | -1       | 01/02/2018
3       | 2         | 2       | 150.00      | 4     | 5        | 03/02/2018

Payee
PayeeId | PayeeName   
1       | Employer 1
2       | Woolworths 

Category
CatId   | CatName
1        | Bills
2        | Income  
3        | Transfer
4        | Groceries        

SubCategory
SubCatId | SubCategoryName | CatId
1        | Salary          | 2
2        | Rent            | 1
3        | Taxes           | 1
4        | Interest        | 2
5        | Food            | 4
```

And my SQL so far is

```
SELECT TransId, Transdate, PayeeName, TransAmount
FROM  Transactions AS t
left JOIN Payee AS p ON t.PayeeId  = p.PayeeId 
join Category as c on c.CATEGID = t.CATEGID
WHERE 
    t.AccountId  = 1
order by Date Desc
```

For the most part his actually works, except when I try to concat two strings (SQLite) code below (I have issues getting Concat to work in MSSQL Express)

CATEGNAME || " : " || SubCat.SUBCATEGNAME as Category

```
SELECT TransId, Transdate, PayeeName, TransAmount,
       CatName || " : " || SubCategoryName as Category
FROM  Transactions AS t
left JOIN Payee AS p ON t.PayeeId  = p.PayeeId 
join Category as c on c.CATEGID = t.CATEGID
join SubCategory as sc on sc.CATEGID = c.CATEGID
WHERE 
    t.AccountId  = 1
order by Date Desc
```

That query returns a record for every SubCategory, which is where I believe I need to be using the group by in the query. The issue is that every time I try that, I am getting the error that I mentioned above.

So two questions, what needs to be done to get this to return the data without geting extra rows for each sub category and how does concat work in MS SQL to achieve what I need. as Concat seems to work on columns, so putting the " : " between the two doesn't wont to play ball with me.

Any help or direction would be fantastic.

**Edit:**

I sort of have it working now.

```
SELECT TransId, Transdate, PayeeName, TransAmount,
       CatName || " : " || SubCategoryName as Category
FROM  Transactions AS t
left JOIN Payee AS p ON t.PayeeId  = p.PayeeId 
left join Category as c on c.CATEGID = t.CATEGID
left join SubCategory as sc on sc.CATEGID = t.CATEGID
WHERE 
    t.AccountId  = 1
order by Date Desc
```

Except that MS SQLite has an issue where instead of being null for category, the concat does this

```
   Bill :
```

Where SQLite itself returns the expected null, is

```
concat(CATEGNAME , ' : ' , SUBCATEGNAME)
```

The right way to do this in MSSQLite?

**Edit 2 :**

Expected results are

```
TransId | Transdate  | PayeeName  | TransAmount | Category
----------------------------------------------------------
1       | 01/02/2018 | Employer 1 | 100         | Income : Salary
```

Now CatId can be null and so can SubCatId

So if CatId is null Category should be null

if Sub Cat is null then Category should be "Income"

and if both have a value then Category should be as the above records returned show. I hope that makes sense.

**Edit 3:**

Ok after a bit of playing around I managed to get it working in SQLite with the following code added to the query

```
            CASE WHEN SUBCATEGNAME IS NULL then CATEGNAME else 
            CASE WHEN CATEGNAME IS NULL then '' else CATEGNAME || ' : ' || SUBCATEGNAME END
            end as Category,
```

And in MS SQlite I was able to get it working with the following instead.

```
           CASE WHEN SUBCATEGNAME IS NULL then CATEGNAME else 
               CASE WHEN CATEGNAME IS NULL then '' else concat(CATEGNAME, ' : ', SUBCATEGNAME) END
           end as Category,
```

Now I guess, that works, but I was hoping for a more cross database solution. As at the moment I am using MS SQLite, but I am not sure I am going to stick with that. Alternatively, would it be better to convert that query to Entity Framework instead?

Comment: Can you please add what final output you need.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. The output should be either "Bill : rent" if both exist or just "Bill" if the sub is null

Comment: ANd of course "" if both are null